# ArrayList getter and setter in a class java

Tags: java, class, arraylist

```
public class Employee                                               
{
private String name;
private String department;


private ArrayList<Employee>job= new ArrayList();
```

// just want to add getter and setter for this ArrayList

```
public void setJob(Employee j)
{
job.add(j);
```

// this is my setter

I want to be able to add later on as many 'job' as I want by extending the arraylist

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Just want to know how to set the setter and getter in my class , thanks

Comment: You can add as many as you want by simply calling your `setJob` method over and over, but what is the getter supposed to return? The first Employee? The last Employee? An `Iterable` of Employees?

Answer (score 3):

While you *can* have setters and getter of `List` type, you should think carefully about their implementation, because most lists are mutable.
For instance, assume that you want to validate that the `jobs` list is not empty.

```
public void setJob(List<Employee> jobs) {
  if (jobs.isEmpty()) throw new RuntimeException();
  this.job = jobs;
}
```

Now the following code produces an employee without jobs:

```
Employee e = ...;
e.setJobs(jobs);
jobs.clear();
//the employee now has no jobs :-(
```

You can avoid this issue by making a [defensive copy](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=15)

```
public void setJob(List<Employee> j) {
  this.job = new ArrayList<>(j);
}
```

The same applies to the getter. If you implement it as:

```
public List<Employee> getJobs() {
   return this.jobs;
}
```

you are allowing the caller to modify the private job list without invoking the corresponding setter: `myEmployee.getJobs().clear()`.

In this case, you may return an unmodifiable list instead of returning the inner object.

```
public List<Employee> getJobs() {
   return java.util.Collections.unmodifiableList(this.jobs);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ordinarily for a collection or array you would use addJob, removeJob and getJobs instead of a get/set pair.

Comment: does that mean I cannot use setters and getters ?

Comment: It is part of an exercise to do for a test so I need to use setters and getters , thanks

Comment: You can do whatever you like, there are no rules, only guidelines.